# Unable to add Scroll to the content and the side bar div seperately

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am trying to add scroll bar seperately to side bar and main content using css. I tried adding overflow variables to both the div container but it is adding the scroll to whole page which is common for both sidebar and main content. Side bar and main content are in a row using flex.

Note : I'm very new to SCSS/CSS and its react app where I'm trying out to add some styling.

Code Sandbox : https://g0mbs.csb.app/

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The element `.main-content-with-side-bar .main-side-bar` needs a `height` set.

IE:

```
.main-content-with-side-bar .main-side-bar {
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    position: relative;
    height: 950px;
}
```

If you don't know exactly what height it needs to be via `px` you can use `calc()` IE `height:calc(100% - 300px);` OR you can set the height dynamically after the page loads with React/ JavaScript / jQuery etc etc etc.

Comment: Both suggestion worked but now I have 3 scrollbar. 1 for the main content, another for side bar and 3rd for both.

Comment: In that case build a main "wrapper" with a max height of 100% and put everything inside of it with a `overflow-y:scroll` -- This will remove the need for the body's scroll bar ..

Comment: Adding below to the body remove the body scroll. Thanks @Zak


overflow:hidden;

Answer (score 1):

Overflow only works when the content exceeds a certain point which in this case has to be forced with height.

You can add the following properties to these css classes:

```
.main-content-with-side-bar .padded-side-bar {
    ...
    height: calc(100vh - 42px);
    overflow: auto;
}

.main-content-with-side-bar .padded-main-content {
    ...
    height: calc(100vh - 42px);
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Or if you are using SCSS:

```
.main-content-with-side-bar {
    .padded-side-bar {
        ...
        height: calc(100vh - 42px);
        overflow: auto;
    }
    .padded-main-content {
        ...
        height: calc(100vh - 42px);
        overflow: auto;
    }
}
```

And that should certainly do the job.

Edit: Updated the height as `height: calc(100vh - 42px);` where `42px` is the height of your header.

Comment: Both suggestion worked but now I have 3 scrollbar. 1 for the main content, another for side bar and 3rd for both @Saurabh Sharma

Comment: @HarshEc Check the updated answer. just use height: calc(100vh - 42px);

Comment: Also remove `overflow-y: scroll;` from `.main-content-with-side-bar .main-side-bar`. That is not needed anymore.

Comment: Adding below to the body remove the body scroll. Thanks @Saurabh Sharma

overflow:hidden

Comment: using `overflow:hidden` on body is not recommended. Try my solution above and you won't see any extra scrollbars

Comment: It eventually gets displayed for different zoom level.